# Sqlite query - order results with numbers last

Tags: sqlite, sorting

I would like to perform an SQLite query and order my results with numbers last.

Eg:

SQLite will ordinarily order results like this when I specify ASC on a text field:

0,
1,
2,
A,
B,
C

Whereas I would like this:

A,
B,
C,
0,
1,
2

Any ideas? Is this possible?

Thanks!

Nick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know nothing about sqllite, but something like this should work (assuming, of course, that there is some sort of `isnumeric` function available):-

```
order by isnumeric(colA), colA
```

so that your non-numerics appear first.

Comment: A clever answer, I just tried it out and there doesn't appear to be an isnumeric function however. (SQL error: no such function: isnumeric). I'll take a look to see if it has a different name in SQLite.

Comment: According to the docs, performing a mathematical operation on a non-numeric value results in null. Could you then use 'ISNULL(colA + 1) DESC' instead of 'isnumeric(colA)'?

Comment: I checked that, and no luck... but on a bit of further Googling it seems IFNULL can be used also. 'order by IFNULL(colA + 1, 0), colA' seemed to do what I need! Thankyou for your help!!

Comment: I wanted to sort the rows with numbers first, then letters. Here's the completed SQL statement I used. `SELECT name FROM tables ORDER BY name, IFNULL(name + 1, 0)`